# Using DataSets and DataTables, Microsoft opinion

Tags: .net

I heard that microsoft does not recommend using DataSets and DataTables in new projects. Instead it recommends using their new technologies or build own class structures. Is that true? If yes, then could someone please give me the official link. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if they've made it "official" but it's been a pretty strong opinion of many .NET people I work with and know that using DataSets in a large scale system is a bad idea and should be avoided.